# shell: write integer division result to a variable and print floating number

Tags: shell, unix, math

I'm trying to write a shell script and plan to calculate a simple division using two variables inside the script. I couldn't get it to work. It's some kind of syntax error.

Here is part of my code, named test.sh

```
    awk '{a+=$5} END {print a}' $variable1 > casenum
    awk '{a+=$5} END {print a}' $variable2 > controlnum
    score=$(echo "scale=4; $casenum/$controlnum" | bc)
    printf "%s\t%s\t%.4f\n", $variable3 $variable4 $score
```

It's just the $score that doesn't work.

I tried to use either

```
sh test.sh
```

or

```
bash test.sh
```

but neither worked. The error message is:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

Does anyone know how to make it work? Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you intend for `awk` to read from a file named in the variable `$variable1`?  And do you really want the output of that awk script to go to a file named `casenum` which happens to be the name of a variable that you use in the echo?  I suspect your problems are primarily the result of confusion about basic shell syntax.

Comment: exactly, fedorqui's answer mentioned the same thing. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are outputting to files, not to vars. For this, you need `var=$(command)`. Hence, this should make it:

```
casenum=$(awk '{a+=$5} END {print a}' $variable1)
controlnum=$(awk '{a+=$5} END {print a}' $variable2)
score=$(echo "scale=4; $casenum/$controlnum" | bc)
printf "%s\t%s\t%.4f\n", $variable3 $variable4 $score
```

Note `$variable1` and `$variable2` should be file names. Otherwise, indicate it.

Comment: $variable1 and $variable2 are variables in my script. They were working fine. What would you do to indicate it?

Comment: i see. For simplicity I didn't include the previous lines. They are used as variable. I just accepted it!

Comment: Great, now I understand, @user2157668 :)

Answer (score 1):

First your `$variable1` and `$variable2` must expand to a name of an existing file; but that's not a syntax error, it's just a fact that makes your code wrong, unless you mean really to cope with files containing numbers and accumulating the sum of the fifth field into a file. Since `casenum` and `controlnum` are not assigned (in fact you write the awk result to a file, not into a variable), your score computation expands to

```
score=$(echo "scale=4; /" | bc)
```

which is wrong (Syntax error comes from this).

Then, the same problem with `$variable3` and `$variable4`. Are they holding a value? Have you assigned them with something like

```
  variable=...
```

? Otherwise they will expand as "". Fixing these (including assigning casenum and controlnum), will fix everything, since basically the only syntax error is when bc tries to interpret the command `/` without operands. (And the comma after the printf is not needed).

The way you assign the output of execution of a command to a variable is

```
  var=$(command)
```

or

```
  var=`command`
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your commands properly, you could combine calculation of *score* with a single `awk` statement as follows

```
score=$(awk 'NR==FNR {a+=$5; next} {b+=$5} END {printf "%.4f", a/b}' $variable1 $variable2)
```

This is with assumption that `$variable1` and `$variable2` are valid file names

Refer to *@fedorqui*'s solution if you want to stick to your approach of 2 awk and 1 bc.